# PMP certification for a non-technical project Manager

Tags: career

I need a guidance on an important situation in my life. I dont have anyone to ask and I find this is the only suitable place to ask this.

I'm into QA management for 4 years and project management field now for 4 years. I'm finding it is not up-gradable to any further and I'm getting stagnated in my current Industry [Mobile Gaming]. And, PM has very less scope of work compared to other industries.

I'm into non-technical position, but I manage technical and non-technical staff. I'm not into coding or programming at any point in my career.

PMP certification is something I know that adds value to my profile. But, will that value help me to land into S/w IT jobs ?

I need insights on this. I'm stuck in my career.

Comment: I think this question is more appropriate for workplace.stackexchange.com.  This is an opinion related question - PM:SE prefers questions that are answerable, practical and of value to the practice of project management.  I'm not sure what you mean when you say, "PM has very less scope of work compared to other industries".  And I'm not sure that any answer you get here is going to be helpful.  If one person says "yes" and the next person says "no", how will you select the right answer?

Answer (score 1):

The IT industry seems to value the PMP over other industries so you may be finding hiring managers using the PMP as a differentiator.  But you are the only person that can answer that based on what you are seeing in your geographical area.

That said, I would not advise you to expect miracles from the PMP certification, i.e., you will not have people knocking down your door now that you have it.

The IT industry needs both technical and non technical people to run successful projects; however, there is a huge bias towards technical people.  This is the halo / horn effect.  Technical people have the halo; non technical have the horns.  In reality, both populations have inherent weaknesses each needs to overcome but the weaknesses technical people generally have are under valued and assumed to be easily mitigated.  And vice versa for the non technical folks.  But non technically people have successfully delivered a technical project and technical people have successfully hosed a technical project.  But the biases will remain.

This is what you are fighting and the PMP, if it helps, will only help a tiny bit.  So you need to find other ways to fight this bias.